# Creating a Neat delay function using NSTimer - Swift

Tags: xcode, function, swift, delay, nstimer

I am trying to create a simple and neat function that uses NSTimer to add a delay to what is ever in the brackets. For e.g.

```
 func Adddelay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
  //Code in here using NSTimer that will add a delay for as long as stated in delay (the number passed in)
    }
```

From this, i am trying to aim to use it by going:

```
delay(1){
//Code in here that will execute after a delay of one second
}
```

The function NEEDS to use NSTimer for what i am using it for as a whole.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong about http://stackoverflow.com/a/29338910/1187415 ?

Comment: It does work fine but I understand NSTimer and know how to utilities it for what I need, I just need help turning it into a simple function for easier use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case, you need to use extension for NSTimer. Published on gist: https://gist.github.com/dimpiax/e2adc74c25d76d124fc3

**Update:**

Published lib: https://github.com/dimpiax/RichTimer